# Unable to build my flutter app when adding google_mobile_ads

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, google-mobile-ads

I have the following issue and already added the dependency implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0' on my build.gradle and updated my manifest accordingly but still unable to build my app. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring project ':google_mobile_ads'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':google_mobile_ads:classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
Required by:
    project :google_mobile_ads
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
Remote host terminated the handshake
```